# Counting Number of Draws Needed to See All Items

Tags: r

I wrote this R code that samples with replacement 5 numbers from 1-100, and then counts the number of random "draws" needed to see each number at least once

```
numbers <- 1:100
sampled <- vector()
counter <- 0

while(length(unique(sampled)) < length(numbers)) {
  new_sample <- sample(numbers, 5, replace = TRUE)
  sampled <- c(sampled, new_sample)
  counter <- counter + 1
  cat("Draw", counter, ":", paste(new_sample, collapse = ", "), "\n")
}
cat("All numbers have been seen at least once after", counter, "draws.")
```

How can I change this code so that it counts the number of times needed to view each number at least twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a "dictionary" in `sampled` that stores how many times each number has been counted. Heads up: if you're dealing with anything other than a strict contiguous vector of integers starting from 1, we need to associate them using the `character` version of the numbers instead of the sampled integers themselves, since otherwise it will index on the integer index and not the named index. (This is not truly a good "dictionary" but works well-enough.)

```r
numbers <- 1:100
sampled <- setNames(rep_len(0L, length(numbers)), numbers)
counter <- 0

while (any(sampled < 2)) {
  new_sample <- as.character(sample(numbers, 5, replace = TRUE))
  tb <- table(new_sample)
  sampled[names(tb)] <- sampled[names(tb)] + tb
  counter <- counter + 1
  cat("Draw", counter, ":", paste(new_sample, collapse = ", "), "\n")
}
```

And once I ran this (I've omitted the noisy commentary), I have

```r
set.seed(42)
### run the above while loop ...

counter
# [1] 139
sampled
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
#   5   7  11   3   7   7   5   8   6  14   6   5   8   8   5   5   6   8   6  12 
#  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
#   6   6   4   9   7   7   9  12   7   9   7   6   7  14   7   6  10   6   4   5 
#  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60 
#   6  14  10   2  12   7   6   3   9   4   5   5   7  10   8   7   8   9   6   6 
#  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80 
#   9   8   6   3   8   3   3   5   6   5   4   3   7   8   6   4   2   4   6   8 
#  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
#   7   9   4  10  11   6   8   4  10   7   5  12   6   4   8   7   9  11   5  10
```

indicating that `44` and `77` were the last two to be sampled twice, and three numbers were sampled 14 times:

```r
sampled[sampled == 2]
# 44 77      # <--- the numbers sampled
#  2  2      # <-   their sampling count
sampled[sampled == max(sampled)]
# 10 34 42   # <--- the numbers sampled
# 14 14 14   # <-   their sampling count
```

Comment: Good point ... Will fix shortly